# How to wrap the shell command in os.system of Python?

Tags: python, shell

It can get a file named `myFile.txt`, in which the content is:

```
file  '/home/debian/1.flv'  
file  '/home/debian/2.flv'  
file  '/home/debian/3.flv'  
file  '/home/debian/4.flv'  
file  '/home/debian/5.flv'
```

Now I want to wrap it in Python

```
os.system("seq  --format="file  '/home/debian/%G.flv'" 5 > myFile.txt" )    
File "<stdin>", line 1  
os.system("seq  --format="file  '/home/debian/%G.flv'" 5 > myFile.txt" )  
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**How to Wrap it in Python?**

1. I do understand how to create the file in Python (kvivek)
2. It is my target to understand how to use complicated shell command in Python,
   If the number of lines is a variable?

There is still a problem with

1. @Torxed escape character way

   ```
   >>> i=7    
   >>> os.system("seq --format=\"file '/home/debian/%G.flv'\" %d > myFile.txt" %i )  
   Traceback (most recent call last):  
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
   TypeError: float argument required, not str
   ```
2. [@ganachoco's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14809797/1931274) triple quotes way

   ```
   >>> os.system('''seq  --format="file  '/home/debian/%G.flv'" %d > myFile.txt" %i''')  
   sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
   ```

there are two staus to be considered,
status 1:
the variable is in the shell, we can do (I had verified the following tow shell commands)

```
root@debian:/home/debian# i=7
root@debian:/home/debian# seq --format="file '/home/debian/%G.flv'" $i > myFile.txt
```

How to wrap it in Python with os.system?

```
>>> os.system('i=7')
0
>>> os.system("seq --format=\"file '/home/debian/%G.flv'\" $i > myFile.txt")
seq: missing operand
Try `seq --help' for more information.
256
```

The variable is in the Python, now I want to call the shell command to put the variable from Python into the shell, how can I do?

```
>>> i=7  #in python prompt
>>> os.system("seq --format=\"file '/home/debian/%G.flv'\" `here i want to get value from python prompt` > myFile.txt")
```

Comment: `os.system("seq  --format=\"file  '/home/debian/%G.flv'\" 5 > myFile.txt" )` ?

Answer (score 3):

quote the " with a backslash

```
for i in (range(1,5)):
    os.system("seq  --format=\"file  '/home/debian/%d.flv'\" > myFile.txt" %i )
```

Answer (score 3):

use triple quote

```
os.system("""seq  --format="file  '/home/debian/%G.flv'" 5 > myFile.txt""")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this gives is what you are looking for

```
[root@localhost ~]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Apr 11 2011, 15:50:32)
[GCC 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> cmdstr = """i=7 && seq --format="file '/home/kvivek/%G.flv'" $i > myFile.txt"""
>>> os.system(cmdstr)
0
>>> exit()
[root@localhost ~]# cat myFile.txt
file '/home/kvivek/1.flv'
file '/home/kvivek/2.flv'
file '/home/kvivek/3.flv'
file '/home/kvivek/4.flv'
file '/home/kvivek/5.flv'
file '/home/kvivek/6.flv'
file '/home/kvivek/7.flv'
[root@localhost ~]#
```